# Calculate the height of a DIV based on other DIVs after loading the page including YouTube iframe

Tags: javascript

I have the following html :

```
<div id="this-is-slide">
  <div id="left" style="float:left;width:70%;">
     <!-- slide here -->
  </div>

  <div id="right" style="float:left;width:30%">
     <div id="rightYT">You Tube video here...</div>
     <div id="RightText">some text here</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here, I have a slide which takes 70% of the width, while the other one (which includes You Tube video) takes 30% of the width. Under the YouTube video content I am having some text.
I want to set height to this div which has text in such a way that the total height of right side content (you tube & text) will be equal to the height of left side content(slider).

To do this I wrote JavaScript under "window.onload" and $(document).ready() but it is not calculating the height of the DIVs properly. I assume that JavaScript is running before EVERYTHING is loaded thereby giving wrong figures for the height at the initial load of the page.

However window resize is working, but at the initial time, its not doing the calculation properly.

This is my JS:

```
<script>

window.onload = function () { resizeRightText(); }

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeRightText();
});

function resizeRightText() {
   var containerHeight = $('#left').height();
   var youtubeHeight = $('#rightYT iframe').height();
   var textHeight = containerHeight - youtubeHeight;
   $('#RightText').css('height',textHeight);
} 

</script>
```

Please let me know how to make it work in such a way that when the page loads FIRST TIME, I WANT TO SET THE HEIGHT TO THE TEXT DIV.

Thanks a bunch,

Comment: can you setup a JSFiddle or JSBin example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Thanks Istos for the reply. I am unable to reproduce it in JSFiddle as its a large wordpress application and its already in production. The client wants to change the existing slider to take only 70% of the width and the rest 30% to YouTube, since its in production and no test environment available I had to do it with the CSS "display:none" at the beginning, this results in returning 0 height and thereby the calculations go wrong. I found it at the last minute though. When test/development environments are not available, I tend to do it in "display:none" and debug in chrome by unblock this CSS